# Is it possible to use C# .dll file in X++ code without adding it into reference?

Tags: c#, dll, interop, axapta, x++

I have the following problem: we developed a C# class which we are planning to use in X++ classes. So, we created a .dll file and added it through reference in X++ project.

However, if we upload the code to the repository and clone it into other machine and try to build the model we will get the bunch of errors where X++ classes which use the C# class can't find it. So we have to add this .dll file again.

I wanted to ask if it is possible for the X++ class to find this .dll file dynamicaly without adding references each time? It is important for us because it can cause some problems in future.

I would be really glad if you help to solve this issue or provide some advice.

Comment: What version of axapta are you using? There are several answers to your question. `\Classes\SysFileDeployer` is something you can use to handle missing assemblies, but that's for 2012.

Comment: I use the one which is integrated with Visual Studio, as I know it's called Dynamics 365 Finance & Operations

Answer (score 1):

You can dynamically locate and load the DLL by storing its path in a configuration file or a database that your application can access. This way, your application can read the path to the DLL at runtime and load it dynamically.

The location could be a network share, a location on disk that is consistent across all environments, or even a cloud storage location.
Here is a general example:

```
System.Reflection.Assembly assembly;
System.Type type;
System.Object obj;
System.Reflection.MethodInfo method;
;

// Load assembly
assembly = System.Reflection.Assembly::LoadFrom(dllPath);

// Get type
type = assembly.GetType("YourNamespace.YourClass");

// Create an instance of the type
obj = System.Activator::CreateInstance(type);

// Get method
method = type.GetMethod("YourMethod");

// Invoke method
var result = method.Invoke(obj, null);
```

In this example, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DllPath"] reads the DLL path from your configuration file. The key "DllPath" should be defined in your configuration file with the path to your DLL.

Please note, you need to have proper access rights to the location where the DLL is stored. And the DLL should be compatible with the platform (x86, x64) of your application.

Comment: You've mentioned "Assembly::LoadFrom", I would like to ask where is it used in your example?

Comment: I fixed it, pls feel free to ask more if its not clear.